# set row background on checkbox clicked inside listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cursoradapter

I have listview with 2 textbox and 1 checkbox on each row.
I want when a user check the checkbox, then a predefined drawable is to be set as a background to that row.

I have tried to do it on the Lisnner on the getView method inside my cusotm cursor adapter, but with no success, please help!!!.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this `getView` method in your `ListAdapter`:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            View row = (View) buttonView.getParent();
            if (isChecked) {
                row.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_background_checked);
            } else {
                row.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            }
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Comment: now, if I want that not only when I click on the checkbox, a background will be set, but also all the rows of which there checkbox is already checked, how would I do that?

Comment: That should be implicit. The `onCheckedChangedListener` also executes when the checkbox is checked/unchecked programmatically. Please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

first of find the checkbox id then,

```
 box.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked) {
                //set background when checked
            }else{
                //when unselect checkbox change background
            }


        }
    });
```

if this code is helful then give +1 or accept.